# getting "undefined local variable or method"

Tags: ruby, macos

Hi I wanted to try to compile this code in mac terminal

```
name = “Dave”
puts “Hello #{name}”
```

but it gives me error

```
undefined local variable or method `“Dave”' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I tried to compile by using ruby hello.rb (hello.rb is the filename)

Thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you're using a text editor rather than a word processor for writing your code.  If you use TextEdit, make sure to set formatting to "Make Plain Text".

Answer (score 3):

Those are some suspicious quotes. Try normal ones.

```
name = "Dave"
puts "Hello, #{name}"
```

Works on my machine.

```
% irb
irb(main):001:0> name = "Dave"
=> "Dave"
irb(main):002:0> puts "Hello, #{name}"
Hello, Dave
=> nil
```

And no, you can't *compile* ruby code (at this stage of your learning).

Comment: oh darn it my comp automatically changes the quotes! I feel so stupid now... Thanks btw!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you fixed your problem (a couple years ago), but for anyone else needing the answer for this question - if you are using TextEdit, go to Edit, Substitutions, and uncheck Smart Quotes.